# What can be said about topological properties of a space $X$ that is homeomorphic to $X\times X$ $?$

Tags: general-topology, examples-counterexamples, product-space

> Given that $X$ is a topological space with infinite cardinality and $X$ is homeomorphic to $X\times X$.
>
> - **(A)**   $X$ cannot be  connected.
> - **(B)**   $X$ cannot be  compact.
> - **(C)**   $X$ cannot be homeomorphic to a subspace of $\mathbb R$.
> - **(D)**   None of the above.

If I take $\mathbb Q$ with discrete topology then $\mathbb Q$  satisfies  the  given condition  while contradicting  option (C).

Now  for  options  (A) and (B), I know if $X$ is *connected* (*compact*) then $X\times X$ will be *connected* (*compact*).

But I cannot  think  of  any examples  of  connected  or  compact  spaces  that  are  homeomorphic  to  their  two-fold  product.

Can anyone  provide with  some  examples?